# How to add nodes after json data is loaded in force layout D3.js?

Tags: d3.js

How can add nodes in the force layout of D3 after json is loaded.
Please check with the below image 
[image]

I just want add four nodes without links at the corner of the layout.

Comment: Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/aVhd8/242/

Comment: There's a short tutorial on how to modify the force layout after it has been started [here](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/d3-force-layout-internals).